# How to create a Node.js program that runs the same on all supported platforms

Tags: node.js, cross-platform

I want to create a Node.js application that runs on Windows, Mac and most linuxes. Is that easy? Are there any good examples of such? What do I need to take into account to do it? I understand file-path separator is one important issue. Are there others?

I'd like to hear if anybody has actual experiences
and "gotchas" they've encountered when creating 
a cross-platform Node.js application. Thanks

Comment: The question is too broad. You don't even mention what an app is supposed to do. You need to take everything that can affect cross-platform compatibility into account. Doesn't sound useful, does it? A single answer can't provide you with all necessary information and spare you several years of hard work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with https://stackoverflow.com/users/3731501/estus, the question is a bit broad in regards to what functionality you'd like to have in your application.

With that said, it may very well be impossible to create any application that executes the same across all platforms, but you should be able to achieve near functional parity with a bit of understanding and effort.

The main issues you'll encounter are around file systems. The node.js team has created a great guide on [working with different filesystems](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/working-with-different-filesystems/), and would be a good start in at least understanding some of the best practices and approaches to to handling the differences and utilizing the `fs` module on different platforms.

Whatever other intricacies and considerations around platform dependent operations you may have are inevitably tied to what your application is trying to do. Once that's determined, you'll need to address those differences by reviewing whatever module you're using to execute the expected functionality and coding for the deviations. The documentation for the api's in the node.js common library are very good at exposing any behavioral or functional differences across operating systems, so if using those, you should at the very least know how those modules and corresponding methods behave on host systems. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer. Maybe I should have titled my question "What are some gotchas in trying to create cross-platform Node.js applications", It's a broad question but at the same time an important one for most Node.js non-toy projects. In the end you want to be able to write as portable code as possible.     I found this article as well in case others are interested in this topic, https://shapeshed.com/writing-cross-platform-node/ .   As I mentioned in my question I'm especially interested in "gotchas" and actual experiences in writing cross-platform Node.js.